# Create Polls with Open Graph?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to create polls trough my Facebook App.
The polls are premade and users will post them to their timeline.

Would really like them to be displayed as Facebook polls/questions already are.

Tried this with no success; https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask the user for the `stream_publish` permission and you will be able to post questions to their timeline.

Your API call will need to be something like:

`POST me/questions?question={your_question}&options={answers_as_json}`&allow_new_options={true|false}`

e.g.:

`POST me/questions?question=Do you like this Question&options=["Yes", "No"]&allow_new_options=false`

Answer (score 0):

You can post a question on behalf of the user by issuing an HTTP POST request to PROFILE_ID/questions with the publish_stream permissions and the appropriate parameters.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#questions for more info.